# Something about LinkedList

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am very new in Java and met some trouble when learning LinkedList.

I am stuck at this problem:
Write a method takeSmallerFrom that compares two lists of integers, making sure that the first list has smaller values in corresponding positions. Either one of lists can be longer than another.

And my attempting solution is below:

```
public void takeSmallerFrom(LinkedIntList other) {
if(front != null && other.front != null) {
    ListNode temp = front.next;
    ListNode prev = front;
    if(front.next != null && other.front != null) {
        if(front.data > other.front.data) {
            front.next = other.front.next;
            other.front.next = temp;
            front = other.front;
            other.front = prev;
        }
        ListNode current = other.front;
        while(prev.next.next != null && current.next.next != null) {
            if(prev.next.data > current.next.data) {
                temp = prev.next;
                prev.next = current.next;
                current.next = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
                current.next.next =prev.next.next;
                prev.next.next = temp; 
            } 
            prev = prev.next;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

The result shows that my solution failed after the first ListNode, but I can't find the reason why the rest of them failed. I am really stuck at this, if anyone here can help me, thank you!

### Sorry I didn't clarify: "front" means the head which leads my LinkedList

The whole solution is for a special LinkedList which only stores int, so I need to compare the each int value in these LinkedLists respectively

Comment: It 's not clear what you are trying to compare. What ist "front" ?

Comment: "front" is a head name which lead my LinkedList, and I need to compare the int value in two LinkedList

Comment: `while(prev.next.next != null && current.next.next != null)` will throw exception if either of `prev.next` or `current.next` is null.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, and I changed this. But the solution is still not working, I think there must be some problems in my solution.

Comment: The question is about "lists of integers", not linked list, isn't it ?

Comment: It seems that next is a reference, so `front.next = other.front.next;` (at this point `temp` also be set `other.front.next`) and other lines seems to try to point same objects like that.

Comment: instead of `temp = temp.next;
                current.next.next =prev.next.next;
                prev.next.next = temp;`  do `curr = prev.next; prev = temp;`

Comment: ummm I tried to edit my code as you told, but it's still not working

Answer (score -1):

If i understood correct, heres an idea:

There are a few issues in your code that need to be addressed:

1. Comparison of values: The condition if(front.data > other.front.data) compares the values of the nodes in the first list with the values of the nodes in the second list. However, your task states that you need to ensure the first list has smaller values in corresponding positions. In other words, you should compare values at the same positions in both lists. To fix this, you need to modify the comparison logic.
2. Swapping nodes: In the code segment front = other.front; and other.front = prev;, you are swapping the entire nodes instead of just their values. This can lead to incorrect results and a broken linked list structure. Instead, you should swap the values of the nodes.
3. Loop conditions: The conditions prev.next.next != null and current.next.next != null in the while loop check for the next two nodes, which can cause issues if one of the lists is shorter than the other. You should change the conditions to prev.next != null and current.next != null to ensure the loop terminates correctly.
4. Incorrect node connections: In the inner loop, you are incorrectly reconnecting the nodes after swapping their values. The lines temp = temp.next;, current.next.next = prev.next.next;, and prev.next.next = temp; are unnecessary and can lead to incorrect connections.

Try to use this:

```
enter code here
public void takeSmallerFrom(LinkedIntList other) {
if (front != null && other.front != null) {
    ListNode prev = null;
    ListNode current = other.front;

    while (front != null && current != null) {
        if (front.data > current.data) {
            int temp = front.data;
            front.data = current.data;
            current.data = temp;
        }

        prev = front;
        front = front.next;
        current = current.next;
    }

    if (current != null) {
        prev.next = current;
    }
}
```

}

In this code, we iterate through both lists simultaneously, comparing values and swapping them when necessary. After the loop, if the second list is longer, we append the remaining nodes of the second list to the end of the first list.